# Forge: Encrypt large file

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, forge

I use [forge framework](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) for some kind of PGP realization. So I need to encrypt very larg file (2gb or more) and keep it encrypted. I want to use as small RAM memory as possible.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general design issue -- not so much related to forge. Like [MDG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531822/mdg) said, you'll need to use streaming to avoid keeping the whole file and encrypted file in memory.

Forge's cipher objects (see: [AES](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#aes)) will allow you to consume chunks of data from a stream. You can do `cipher.update()` to encrypt an arbitrarily-sized chunk of data from a stream and then call `cipher.output.getBytes()` to clear the internal buffer and get any encrypted output which you can then send somewhere. This should keep your memory usage low.

Keep in mind that the bytes you get from a forge buffer will be encoded in a string. The string encoding type is what node.js recognizes as 'binary'. (It's a way to encode bytes in a JS string for browsers that don't support TypedArrays, which many browsers did not at the time that forge was first written). If you're talking to a node.js server, you can just put this string into a `Buffer` using the 'binary' encoding. If you're talking to another server, you may want to base64 encode them before transmission. You can do this using `forge.util.encode64`.

You may also want to check out [OpenPGP.js](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs).

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting large files should be stream based for low memory usage, You can have a look at node's built in [crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module or try out different packages on npm ([file-encryptor](https://www.npmjs.org/package/file-encryptor) for example)